# Use of infinity in physics

Tags: mathematics, singularities

There have been lots of questions on this site about the use of infinity in different ways in physics.

- Infinitely big - [Physics near null infinity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498716/37364)
- Infinitesimals - [Using differentials in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664479/37364)
- Renormalization - [A simple, easily understandable example of infinities making trouble in physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/613958/37364)

This is all fine. But one mathematically ordinary use of infinity bothers me. You can show the counting numbers and the even numbers have the same size by mapping 1->2, 2->4, and so on. This obviously fails if you try it with the counting numbers and even numbers below n. You run out of even numbers around n/2. No problem - make n bigger. Now it takes longer to run into trouble. And when you do the trouble is bigger. But for the full set, you never have to settle the accounts. You sweep the infinitely big error under an infinitely distant rug.

This makes me squirm a little. You can use this idea to prove unphysical results like the Banach-Tarski theorem. Vsauce [demonstrates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA) how this idea leads to the ability to cut a sphere into 5 "pieces" and put them back together into two spheres. Of course, you can't really cut out the infinitely detailed shaped needed to do this.

But he says that some physicists think this is physical. Some paper have been written using this idea. For example to explain things about quark confinement. He doesn't explain the application to physics. Can anyone enlighten me? Hopefully with a reasonably simple explanation.

---

There is also the use of

$$1+2+3 + ... = -\frac{1}{12}$$

in string theory. But this might not be the same thing. This isn't true if you just add natural numbers and see what it converges to.

This has something of the flavor of how p-adic numbers work. For p-adics, the norm is different. Numbers that differ in bigger digits are closer together, as explained in [The Most Useful Numbers You've Never Heard Of](https://www.veritasium.com/videos/2023/6/6/the-most-useful-numbers-youve-never-heard-of).

[To sum 1+2+3+⋯ to −1/12](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39802/294354) outlines several ways of showing this sum, including one by Euler.

For more about the use in string theory, see

- [Why are extra dimensions necessary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10527)
- [A simple and rigorous proof of 26/10 dimensions in string theory](http://rantonels.github.io/critical-dimension/) …does not exist.

Comment: "String theory" should not be one's first exposure to the Casimir effect.

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of your question?

Comment: Has 1+2+3+... in string theory been used to predict an experimental result? (that's a joke obviously the answer is no) There's also a claim floating around in pop science discussions that this sum is used to calculate the strength of the Casimir effect. But take a look at a real derivation-the argument is much more reasonable. There is an infinite part of the sum which doesn't change with the distance between the plates and a finite part which does change, and that's what gives rise to the force. The argument is good and does not depend on this unreasonable value for a clearly infinite sum.

Comment: A lot of my question talks about uses of infinity in physics. One use bothers me, and yet it too has been used. The actual question is "He doesn't explain the application to physics. Can anyone enlighten me? Hopefully with a reasonably simple explanation." Sorry if I have wrapped it with to much side issue.

Comment: Never mind. I see J Murray's answer.

Comment: You write "You can use this idea [i.e. the proof that the natural numbers are Dedekind-infinite]  to prove ... the Banach-Tarski theorem. " Well, actually, no you can't.  The natural numbers are Dedekind-infinite in any model of ZF, but Banach-Tarski requires the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You sweep the infinitely big error under an infinitely distant rug.

You lose me a bit here - there is no error to sweep. Two sets have the same cardinality if and only if the elements of each can be put into one-to-one correspondence with the elements of the other. That is true of $\mathbb N$ and $2\mathbb N$, as you say. No problem.

Now, if two sets $A$ and $B$ both have a finite number of elements, then they have the same cardinality if and only if they have the same number of elements. In this way, cardinality reduces to "number of elements" **for finite sets**. For non-finite sets, "number of elements" is not a meaningful notion.

> This makes me squirm a little. You can use this idea to prove unphysical results like the Banach-Tarski theorem. [...] But he says that some physicists think this is physical. Some paper have been written using this idea. For example to explain things about quark confinement.

I found [only one paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Hadron-physics-and-transfinite-set-theory-Augenstein/cd3317ef0c13c243ab2f01c76d19a5aed6a3be36) linking Banach-Tarski to hadron physics. Its central thesis is that there is a connection between the two, because it can be shown that the so-called *minimal decomposition* required to implement Banach-Tarski is a single sphere being split into 5 pieces and then reassembled into two spheres, one consisting of 2 pieces and the other consisting of the remaining 3. We are to imagine that the "pieces" are quarks, and that a 2-piece sphere and a 3-piece sphere are a meson and baryon, respectively. The author observes that if this connection exists, then quark confinement is the statement that there does not exist a decomposition in which one of the resulting spheres consists of only one piece.

Personally, this seems ... unlikely to bear much fruit. I suspect the reason for this apparent correspondence can be attributed to the [strong law of small numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_law_of_small_numbers).

Comment: "Infinitely distant rug" - I was thinking analogously to the limit of summing a sequence. We define 1 as the limit of $1/2 + 1/4 + ...$ because the sum of a finite subset gets closer and closer to 1. 1 is the natural extension. But finite mappings get farther and farther from showing the same cardinality of numbers and even numbers. Yes it works because you never run out of numbers, but it isn't a natural extension of finite cases.

Comment: And it doesn't match everyday physics. There is no set of rocks where you can map the full set to a proper subset. Reasoning from the idea leads to wrong answers for everyday physics. There is no sphere that you can cut into 5 pieces and reassemble into 2 spheres. So if there is an application to physics, it must not be a straightforward one. It ought to be interesting. Or as you found, trivial.

Comment: I have no objection to the mathematics. Math is not physics. Math is about the logical consequences of its axioms. These axioms don't have to match the universe to be interesting and useful. A lot of interesting results come from never running out of numbers. It wasn't easy to make it logically consistent.

Comment: @mmesser314 I still have to disagree with you. The first $n$ elements of $\mathbb N$ (i.e. $\{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$) can be (trivially) put in 1-to-1 correspondence with the first $n$ elements of $2\mathbb N$ (i.e. $\{0,2,4,\ldots,2n\}$, for arbitrary $n$, and extending this to $n\rightarrow \infty$ covers every element of each set. You are arguing that the elements of $\mathbb N$ less than $n$ cannot be put into correspondence with the elements of $2\mathbb N$ which are **also** less than $n$ - which is true, but not the question being asked.

Comment: @mmesser314 Your point that infinite sets can have the same cardinality as one of their proper subsets is true, but not at all unusual unless you assume that "cardinality" and "number-of-elements" are the same thing. In any case, infinities can be an extremely useful tool for describing everyday physics - for example, it can be shown that for systems with finitely many particles, there are no phase transitions. Infinity is not to be thrown around lightly, but saying that it is inherently unphysical is going a bit too far, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Fourier analysis is a much more routine example: the Fourier transform is defined by an integral with infinite limits. It gets used all over physics, as well as in other sciences, and even more in engineering.

Everything we do with Fourier analysis could be done without infinite limits, but it would require carrying inner and outer scale parameters through calculations. This tedious process would add confusion but no value.

Infinity is a useful concept in the construction of mathematical models. You should remember George Box's aphorism: "All models are wrong, but some are useful."

Comment: Nielsen's addition to Box's Law is "all engineers are wrong, but some are useful."